# I can't store uploaded images in public laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to upload some pictures and store them in public/ but it store in storage/app/public

i used php artisan link:storage before

And this is the code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $new_file_data=[
            'small_explain'=>$request->input('small_explain'),
            'title'=>$request->input('title'),
            'paragraph_one'=>$request->input('paragraph_one'),
            'paragraph_two'=>$request->input('paragraph_two'),
            'paragraph_list'=>$request->input('paragraph_list'),
            'paragraph_three'=>$request->input('paragraph_three'),
            'important_body'=>$request->input('important_body'),
            'quote'=>$request->input('quote'),
            'author_quote'=>$request->input('author_quote'),

             //image storage

            'index_image' => $request->file('index_image')->store('/public/Images'),
            'header_image' => $request->file('header_image')->store('/public/Images' ),
            'text_image' =>$request->file('text_image')->store('/public/Images'),

        ];
        Article::create($new_file_data);

    }
```

Comment: If you use store method then your file will be saved in storage but if you want to save in public then you have to use move() method.

Comment: but when i use move() images save as .temp

Comment: i add an answer please see this.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, welcome to StackOverflow.

I think you should have a deeper look at the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#configuration)

> The filesystem configuration file is located at `config/filesystems.php`. Within this file you may configure all of your "disks". Each disk represents a particular storage driver and storage location.

This is your problem. In your `filesystems.php` file you have a config as follows (unless you did any changes):

```php
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

    // [...]

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

    ],

];
```

With this configuration, Laravel will take as root for your storage the folder `storage/app` and include your custom path (in this case `storage/app/public/Images`). If you want to save something in the public folder, change the config in this way.

```php
return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'default' => 'public', // <-- Set the default disk

    // [...]

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Filesystem Disks
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path(),    // <-- Change the default path to the public folder
            'url' => env('APP_URL'),    // <-- And the default URL
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

    ],

];
```

Anyway, this is not a best practice. As you wrote, you also used the `php artisan storage:link` command that creates a symlink from the `storage/app/public` folder to the `public/storage` path. In this way, all the files stored in that folder will be visible with commands like `asset('storage/my-public-image.jpg')`.

Moreover Laravel has its [native function](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/filesystem#file-urls) `$url = Storage::url('file.jpg');` that will automatically create an URL based on the config you set (the **url** param in the disk config).

That's why, unless in your production environment you don't have the ability to create symlinks, saving files directly into the public folder is useless and, in most cases, insecure.

Answer (score 0):

if you want use store function then follow @llGala answers. But if you want to use move function then you can use it like below to ignore save as .temp

```
if ($request->image) {
            $file=$request->File('image');
            $ext=$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename=$user->username . '.' . $ext;
            $file->move('images/',$filename);
            $user->image=$filename;
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

First run this in your cmd

```
  php composer require intervention/image
```

Fore more information click to this link
  [http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation]
Use this method

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'small_explain' => 'required',
            'title' => 'required',
            'paragraph_one' => 'required',
            'paragraph_two' => 'required',
            'paragraph_list' => 'required',
            'paragraph_three' => 'required',
            'important_body' => 'required',
            'quote' => 'required',
            'author_quote' => 'required',

            'index_image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,bmp',
        ]);
        $image = $request->file('index_image');
        $slug = str_slug($request->title);

        if(isset($image)) {

            $currentDate = Carbon::now()->toDateString();

            $imagename = $slug.'-'.$currentDate.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            if(!Storage::disk('public')->exists('upload')) {
                Storage::disk('public')->makeDirectory('upload');
            }

            $postImage = Image::make($image)->resize(1600, 1066)->save($imagename);
            Storage::disk('public')->put('upload/'.$imagename, $postImage);
        } else {
            $imagename = 'default.png';
        }
        $article = new Article;
        $article->images = $imagename;
        $article->small_explain = $request->small_explain;
        $article->paragraph_one = $request->paragraph_one;
        $article->paragraph_two = $request->paragraph_two;
        $article->paragraph_list = $request->paragraph_list;
        $article->paragraph_three = $request->paragraph_three;
        $article->important_body = $request->important_body;
        $article->quote = $request->quote;
        $article->author_quote = $request->author_quote;

        $article->save();
        return redirect(route('articles.index'));
    }
```

If your problem is not resolved send me a message

Comment: intervention/image is mainly an image manipulation library. This has nothing to do with the question.